# Confusion about build method in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :boxes
    has_many :books
end

class Box < ActiveRecord::Base
    belong_to :user
    has_many :books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :box
end
```

So when I run below in a console it works as I expect, creating a new box and attaching the user_id to the box

```
>> u = User.first
>> u.boxes.build(:height => 3, :width => 1, :length => 4)
>> u.save
```

So then I go further and attempt this. The box_id is set, but the user_id in books is not set.

```
>> u.boxes.first.books.build(:title => 'Reading is fun')
>> u.save
```

It seems like I'm missing a pretty fundamental concept here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each relationship is distinct from all the others. That is, when you `build` a Book belonging to `u.boxes.first`, all Rails infers is that the Book belongs to that Box; it says nothing about the User.

In this situation, where (presumably) Books are always owned by the person who owns the Box they're in, you're probably best off with a `has_many :through` relationship:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :boxes
    has_many :books, :through => :boxes
end

class Box < ActiveRecord::Base
    belong_to :user
    has_many :books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base        
    belongs_to: box
    delegate :user, :to => :box # since belongs_to doesn't take :through
                                # passes Book#user through to Book#box.user
end
```

If that's not the case (perhaps you're helping me move?), leave the associations as they are, but you'll have to set at least one of the relations up manually, for instance:

```
b = u.boxes.first.books.build(:title => "foo")
b.user = u
b.save

# or...
u.boxes.first.create_book(:title => "foo", :user => u)
```

(Couple of other points. In your second example you should save the Book, not the User; and you can do both `build` and `save` in a single operation with `create`)

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I had a feeling it had to do with a has_many :through relationship.

Comment: Ok, so no matter what, I'm going to need to pass the user id to the book, because it can't see that far back. This is very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Only if you're not using `:through`. If you're using `:through`, the `books` table doesn't need a `user_id` column, and everything's set up automatically via the `Box` model.

Comment: hmmm... are you sure? That is what I had thought originally, but as I'm testing this I'm not getting that result.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. `belongs_to` doesn't take `:through` for some reason. Let me update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

That should be

```
u.boxes.first.books.build(:title => 'Reading is fun', :user_id => u.id)
```

Because you're `build` method here is called for `box`. And `build` works like that:

```
parent.children.build
# The same as:
parent.children.new(:parent_id => parent.id)
```

So here is nothing about grandparents.

Comment: Thank you. That is very helpful. I wish I could give you both the checkmark as you both helped me. I understand completely.